# Spooling out with Union statement in Teradata

Tags: union, teradata, spool

I am unioning all 4 tables with ~300M records each. They have the same PI and I have collected statistics on the PI for each table but I still keep spooling out. Any ideas how to trouble shoot this? Is there another way to combine these tables that's less spool intensive?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `UNION` or `UNION ALL`? Unless you really need to apply `DISTINCT` you better use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Yes I actually want to capture duplicates so am using UNION ALL

Comment: Can  you show the whole query?

Comment: What is the spool limit on your user? Your DBA can provide you this information. Is there a redistribution step in the explain plan? That column might be skewed resulting in the spool outs.

Comment: Also, even if there is a high amount of spool configured for your user, it depends on how many users are simultaneously using it. Too many concurrent users utilizing the same spool can result in spool outs.